# Why are these rendered surfaces reflecting two different colors?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

Why are these rendered surfaces reflecting two different colors? I'm using Cycles and an HDRi for illumination. I've applied scale, UV unwrapped and checked that the normals are facing outward. Thanks for any help.

[image]

[image: Render]

[image: 3D View]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your node setup for the Chrome material, you need to change the Normal Map node type from Tangent to Object. Then you will get the same response on both objects.

Comment: Brilliant! If you have a moment could you explain the reason why so I can understand Cycles better? Thank you.

Comment: Honestly, I spent about an hour trying to track that down. It seems that Tangent normal maps should work fine, but there is definitely something different about the 2 meshes that make their surfaced give different results. I tried a number of things, including combining them into 1 mesh but the surfaces still acted differently. Had to give up.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's probably something to do with the mesh. I started out with it combined and separated it as part of trouble shooting to no avail. Thank you for your time I can move on now...